# Using mask to replace string in numpy array results in truncated string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In a much larger project, I'm using a mask to set colors for a plot based on a series of other inputs. In one set, the default color is `'darkgreen'` unless the mask is `True` then it turns to `'white'`. In the second set, the opposite is true. The code below is a MRE that only includes the mask/array set up.

The section that turns `'darkgreen'` to `'white'` works fine. But when I try to turn `'white'` to `'darkgreen'` it truncates it to `'darkg'`. I'm assuming it is working with the same number of characters in the string, but I'm not sure why or how to fix it! Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30, 2), columns=['A','B'])

a_mask = df['A'] > 0
b_mask = df['B'] > 0

n = 30

uca = ['darkgreen' for i in range(n)]
uca = np.array(uca)
uc = uca.copy()
uc[a_mask] = 'white'
dca = ['white' for i in range(n)]
dca = np.array(dca)
dc = dca.copy()
dc[b_mask] = 'darkgreen'
print(uc)
print(dc)
```

Comment: `numpy` arrays with strings have a fixed character length, e.g. `U10`.  Check the `dtype`.  Writing a longer string to the array results in truncation.  `pandas` uses object dtype for strings, so there's no truncation.

Comment: By the way you can replace `['darkgreen' for i in range(n)]` by `['darkgreen']*n` in uca and same for the dca.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the dtype of your arrays of strings:

```
>>> uca.dtype
dtype('<U9')

>>> dca.dtype
dtype('<U5')
```

The first dtype is 9 character unicode string (the `<` denotes the byte-order (little-endian)) whereas the second is 5 character string. That's why the truncation is happening -- the `dca` array can keep strings with length up to 5 characters. So one way to solve this is to replace `dca = np.array(dca))` in your code by `dca = np.array(dca, dtype=uca.dtype)` to match the dtypes. Or you can use `dtype = object` for both arrays so that they can keep arbitrary length strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use numpy's `where` function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])

a_mask = df['A'] > 0
b_mask = df['B'] > 0

n = 30

uca = ['darkgreen' for i in range(n)]
uca = np.array(uca)
uc = uca.copy()
uc[a_mask] = 'white'
dca = ['white' for i in range(n)]
dca = np.array(dca)
dc = dca.copy()
dc = np.where(b_mask, 'darkgreen', dc)
print(uc)
print(dc)
```

Comment: I'd never encountered this quirk of ndarrays before - usually use them for numbers myself. Don't forget to accept the answer if it resolves your issue ;)